# Fatal Python error: Aborted - randomly happening in code

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder, fatal-error

I don't think I changed anything in my code which was working not long ago, but now I'm getting this error:

```
Fatal Python error: Aborted


Main thread:
Current thread 0x000027c4 (most recent call first):
  File "c:\users\nate\onedrive\documents\github\havoc\hav_pyrometertest_single_frame.py", line 19 in main
  File "c:\users\nate\onedrive\documents\github\havoc\hav_pyrometertest_single_frame.py", line 38 in <module>
  File "C:\Users\nate\miniconda3\envs\spyder_env\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py", line 356 in compat_exec
  File "C:\Users\nate\miniconda3\envs\spyder_env\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 473 in exec_code
  File "C:\Users\nate\miniconda3\envs\spyder_env\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 615 in _exec_file
  File "C:\Users\nate\miniconda3\envs\spyder_env\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 528 in runfile
  File "C:\Users\nate\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_17400\3451480624.py", line 1 in <module>
```

I am using PySpin to take pictures with two cameras, and this error keeps coming up. I have print statements throughout the program to narrow down the issue, but the code doesn't stop at the same place every time it runs.

I've tried narrowing down the issue, but it seems to keep changing what the failure point is. This makes me think it's not the code itself, but something to do with Spyder.

Edit: Code in main file is here:

```
import sys
import time

import HAV_PyrometerFunctions_single_frame as pyr
        
acquisition_duration = 5

def main():

    

    result, cam_list = pyr.initialize_cameras()
    count = 0
    elapsed = 0
    t_start = time.time()

    while elapsed < acquisition_duration:
        try:
            result = pyr.run_multiple_cameras(cam_list)
            count += 1
            elapsed = time.time() - t_start
        except:
            print("error")
    print(count, "images")

    pyr.deinitialize_cameras()

    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if main():
        sys.exit(0)
    else:
        sys.exit(1)
```

The functions file is 500 lines long, but if it would be helpful to see that then I can upload parts of that too.

Comment: Can you please show your code? Kind of hard to reproduce a problem and give solutions without seeing what caused it

Comment: @ViaTech just added some code, my functions file has a lot more though

Comment: Your problem seems to reside in `HAV_PyrometerFunctions_single_frame` class

Comment: @MusabbirArrafi agreed, I actually spent two days trying to narrow down the problem. I would narrow the problem down to one line, then I would delete that line, then the error would occur somewhere else. At some point I had deleted basically everything in the code, and then the error stopped happening. So I hit undo to see what I had changed that had caused it, and the error didn't come back. So I undid it all the way to my original code, which was somehow working again. I still get the fatal error occasionally, and to fix it I just delete almost everything, run the code, and the error leaves.

Comment: I'm so frustrated haha

Comment: can you share the source code so I can reproduce it?